# laravel_echo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.private

Tags: laravel

почему такая ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: laravel_echo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.private is not a function
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:83383)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.0 (app.js:91192)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at app.js:84
    at app.js:87
```

подключил вот так

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '714f186eca09c2ac2b27',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
});


Echo.private('user_notif')
    .listen('UserNotification', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

понял, нужно писать так

```
window.Echo
```